# Numbering of an autoincrement column if sorting another column on alphabet

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

It's a primitive question. I am working on a small project using a database. The database has one of the columns with auto increment and another column with a set of words. Now if I add a new word by insert, it will have a number automatically as I have auto increment. The word will now be added at the bottom. If I sort the words on the basis of alphabetical order, how will the numbering be? Will it automatically be in phase?

Answer (score 2):

The autoincrement column will act as a primary key and it is already sorted. It will not be changed if you sort your columns alphabeticllay

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7e91/3)**